# Encrypt/decrypt for Image on IOS

Tags: ios, encryption, uiimage, aes

We are working with encrypt/decrypt and UIIMAGE. If we are encrypting and decrypting and UIIMAge without save into the iphone gallery, it works fine but If we encrypt, save into the gallery, load (the image encrypted)into the app and decryting it works bad.

We are using this functions to encrypt/decrypt/save/load

//encrypt

```
UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
CGContextRef ctx;
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
int valor =(height * width * 4);
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast |    kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);


    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)rawData length:sizeof(unsigned char)*valor];
   NSData *encryptedData  = [data AES256EncryptWithKey:@"\"thisIsASecre"];


rawData = [encryptedData bytes];


NSData *dataData2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawData length:sizeof(rawData)];

ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                            CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                            8,
                            CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
UIImage *rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

self.imageView.image = rawImage;

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

//decrypt

```
UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
CGContextRef ctx;
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
int valor =(height * width * 4);
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);


   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)rawData length:sizeof(unsigned char)*valor];
   NSData *encryptedData  = [data AES256DecryptWithKey:@"\"thisIsASecre"];


rawData = [encryptedData bytes];




ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                            CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                            8,
                            CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
UIImage *rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

self.imageView.image = rawImage;
image = rawImage;

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

// Load image

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

self.imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

//And the clases i use to encrypt/decrypt

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}
```

Someone know what’s the problem?

Thxs!

Comment: @rmaddy it looks to me as if he is saving a valid image.  He's encrypting the image pixels, then creating an image with the essentially random pixels and storing that in the Photo library.  (Not that he shouldn't be checking the error returns anyway :)

Comment: Aren't images stored in the photo library always converted to jpg?  In which case you'd have a lossy compression and couldn't expect your encryption/decryption cycle to survive.

Comment: @rmaddy He's not encrypting the png or the jpg.  He's encrypting the pixel data itself.  In essence he's just randomizing the color of the individual pixels in the bitmap.  He then converts the randomized pixels into a CGImage and a UIImage, so what he gets is a valid image (although not particularly useful to look at)

Comment: @David Oops - I completely misread this one. Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified that you can go through the encryption/decryption cycle without the photo library in the middle and recover your original photo?  You're storing a bitmap image into the library, it may be stored as JPG.  Have you tried forcing cycling the image through UIImagePNGRepresentation and back?

Comment: @cserrano did you found the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

If you save a bitmap image to the photo library, it gets stored as a JPG.  The lossy format of JPG will completely hose over your encryption process.  Try turning your bitmap image into a PNG image and then saving that:

```
UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(rawImage)];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngImage, nil, nil, NULL);
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your time @David and rmaddy. I tried to do this before (and now) and is not working. With your example, I can encrypt(and save like a png), but if I take the photo encrypted from the library or the image from the UIImage doesn't work.

Comment: Have you verified that you can make the round trip through encryption/decryption and get your original back?

Comment: - First, I take the photo from the camera or gallery and i encrypt. I can see the photo encrypted in a UIImage and i saved it , it works fine.  If a go to the gallery I can see the encrypted photo.
- Second,  with the encrypted image  (from the UIImage  without access gallery), I decrypt correctly(i see the image 'orginal') and i save into the gallery like the original. 
But if I do the second step, taking the encrypted photo from the gallery, then I no longer works. I understand that there must be a problem when you save into  the gallery maybe compress the photo.

Comment: @cserrano did you ever figure out this issue?