# Encrypt / Decrypt UIImage in Swift using AES Encryption

Tags: swift

I am piggybacking off of [Encrypt/decrypt for Image on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269829/encrypt-decrypt-for-image-on-ios) UIImage encryption strategy which uses Obj-c to achieve what I am looking for in Swift. For now, ignore the "save to library" issue there, as I am having issues with decrypting in the app itself.

The encryption step *seems to* work fine, and I do get an encrypted image out to `imageView.image`, but when I try to decrypt I get another image which appears to be encrypted, never back to the original .png image.

Any thoughts as to where I went wrong? AES encryption files here: https://github.com/alexeypro/EncryptDecrypt

Encryption / Decryption:

```
func pixelEncryptDecrypt() {

    let image = imageView.image!
    var imageRef = image.CGImage

    let width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef)
    let height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerPixel: UInt = 4
    let bytesPerRow: UInt = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent: UInt = 8

    let sizeOfRawDataInBytes: Int = Int(height * width * 4)
    var rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.alloc(sizeOfRawDataInBytes)

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue) | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)), imageRef)

    var data = NSData(bytes: rawData, length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes)
    data = encrypted ? data.AES256DecryptWithKey(key) : data.AES256EncryptWithKey(key)

    rawData = data.mutableCopy().mutableBytes

    let cryptContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue))
    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cryptContext);

    let encryptedImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)

    imageView.image = encryptedImage

    encrypted = !encrypted

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the above code was that I assumed the alpha channel of the image, which upon further research was a silly mistake. I replaced the assumed alpha channel of `CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast` with a variable `let alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef)` and passed that variable to both `CGBitmapContextCreate` calls.

```
func pixelEncryptDecrypt() {
    let image = imageView.image!
    var imageRef = image.CGImage

    let width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef)
    let height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerPixel: UInt = 4
    let bytesPerRow: UInt = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent: UInt = 8

    let alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef) // this is what solved the issue.

    let sizeOfRawDataInBytes: Int = Int(height * width * 4)
    var rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.alloc(sizeOfRawDataInBytes)

    var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo(alphaInfo.rawValue) | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)), imageRef)

    var data = NSData(bytes: rawData, length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes)
    data = encrypted ? data.AES256DecryptWithKey(key) : data.AES256EncryptWithKey(key)

    rawData = data.mutableCopy().mutableBytes

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo(alphaInfo.rawValue))
    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    let encryptedImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)

    imageView.image = encryptedImage

    encrypted = !encrypted
}
```

Comment: How in the heck are you supposed to do var context = CGBitmapContextCreate... in Swift 4? My Xcode is generating all kinds of corrections and leading me down the garden path to app crashes. Sometimes I absolutely HATE how hard Swift makes crap. I almost had it. Thanks for the code - I sure hope I can figure out how the heck Swift wants me to freaking update it!

Comment: @andrew were you able to replicate in latest swift version ?